# "if" não corresponde à condição

Tags: php, if, operadores, condição

Estou tentando aplicar um `if` no meu código, mas ele está vindo errado:

```
<?php     
echo $usu_id . "<br />";
echo $centraliz . "<br />";
echo $marca . "<br />";

if($centraliz = "S"){

echo "É centralizada";

} else {

echo "Não é centralizada";

}
?>
```

Porém o resultado está vindo assim:

[image: erro]

Comment: Isso porque você fez uma atribuição dentro do `if`, utilizando o operador `=`. O correto seria dois sinais de iguais para comparar, `==`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um exemplo pratico para melhor entendimento:

```
<?php   
$variavel = 'true';

if($variavel == "true"){
   echo "1";
}
if($variavel == true){
   echo "2";
}
if($variavel === true){
   echo "3";
}
if($variavel = true){
   echo "4";
}
echo $variavel;
```

O valores que serão mostrados na tela: 1, 2, 4 e 1

**($variavel == "true")** = Verdadeiro porque é a mesma string.
**($variavel == true)** = Verdadeiro porque true é igual a true.
**($variavel === true)** = Falso porque true é igual a true, porem os tipos são diferentes, um é uma string e o outro e booleano.
**($variavel = true)** = verdadeiro já que é uma simples atribuição de valor, este caso só será falso se a atribuição falhar, geralmente o retorno falso acontece quando o valor pra comparação vem de uma função, a função pode retorna algo que seja impossível a atribuição.
E o valor 1 do final é o resultado da "$variavel" já que depois do ($variavel = true) o seu valor passou para verdadeiro por causa da atribuição e ao mostrar na tela ele mostra 1 que é verdadeiro para o php, se você fazer assim 'echo true;' o resultado na tela será 1 também.

Answer (score 10):

Mude para

```
if ($centraliz == "S") {
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Operator/ComparingString.php).

O operador `=` é de atribuição, o de `==` é de comparação. Então está afirmando que `centralizada` é `S` e é claro que uma afirmação é sempre verdadeira.  Em algumas situações (não nesta) é até necessário usar o `===` para garantir que os dois operandos sejam do mesmo tipo.